# Magento 1 page layout

Tags: magento

[image]I wanted to change the layout of only one page, which is the category page. I edited the catalog.xml line 187 from 2-columns-right to 1-column but it edited my product page. My question is how can I edit only the category page (where shows all products within a category, see image attached)

Answer (score 1):

You should never modify core files in place, and it is best practice to avoid overriding and customizing core layout files in custom themes. Rather, you should use the *local.xml* layout file. [There is a great tutorial on layout XML customization at MageBase.com](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/).

*local.xml* is being merged into the compiled layout configuration DOM last among all layout XML files, giving its directives a certain authority over others. You should try the following  content:

```
<?xml version-"1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

Remember to clear/disable the layout XML cache while developing.

Comment: Thanks Ben! and yes I agree with you but those are my theme files, and not the base files

Comment: FWIW they shouldn't be in your theme either (according to core team), though sometimes it's unavoidable.

Comment: Ha! I didn't know that! well I guess I should have to read it again! Thank You!